# How to filter everything in one column out of another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have two columns. Column K has a bunch of values, Column L has some of these values. I want to filter everything that appears in Column L out of Column K. How would I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by filtering: doing it in place, temporarily (with a filter or a filter view) or creating a new list that will have the entries from K that are not in L?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to get the values in K that are not appearing in L ? If so (and assuming your data starts on row 2), try:

```
=filter(K2:K, isna(match(K2:K, L2:L,0)))
```

If you only want to see unique values, then try:

```
=unique(filter(K2:K, isna(match(K2:K, L2:L,0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution to calculate intersection of Column K and Column L is:

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(K2:K), (ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIF(UNIQUE(L2:L), ARRAYFORMULA( UNIQUE(K2:K) ))))>0)
```

Please, see prepared example here: **[Columns Intersection](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cdWJ87LeT0yOFRIxO8g2BeroboEqna1znuAzVCZoJzs/edit?usp=sharing)**